# Prestashop - Paypal Web hosted Solution IFrame Integration

Tags: php, iframe, paypal-sandbox, prestashop

I'm working on Paypal web hosted solution (sand box). In that i would like to integrate with IFrame. but when i integrate sometime the iframe is loaded but when i work with new browser or new proxy server it does not load the iframe. rather if i logged already in paypal account. the iframe is loading

the problem is that iframe should work when i load the page.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/web-checkout/using-paypal-iframe

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: Hosted Solution is a new product that allows irame in templateD mode. 
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/HostedSolution.pdf - chapter 4

To address the question - I'd try live. To use Sandbox you must be logged into developer.paypal.com. When using proxies you may lose the login along the way and the iframe will try to display "you must log in" page which cannot be iframed.

I hope this helps.

Michael

Answer (score -1):

Paypal does not allow integration using an iFrame.