# Prestashop embedded in iframe or object tag does not progress to paypal payments page?

Tags: object, iframe, paypal, prestashop

first post but longtime reader.

I'm trying to embed a prestashop store in an existing website. It seems to work fine, until you get to the 'checkout with paypal' step. When you click 'checkout with paypal' you get the page-load icon on the browser tab but then nothing happens and you remain on the same page.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805795/prestashop-paypal-web-hosted-solution-iframe-integration) from 2011 its impossible to embed paypal in an iframe. Is this still the case and does it apply to object frames as well?

You can demo the site at www.demoiselle.com.au/test/#store to test out the problem I'm having. I also tried this with an object tag but the same outcome happens.

Any ideas if what I'm trying to do is possible and if not, any suggestions for a way to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your code of what you have tried?

Comment: You can see it at http://www.demoiselle.com.au/test/#store for the iframe version and http://www.demoiselle.com.au/test/index-original.html#store for the object tag. In both situations it's a simple iframe/object that is loading http://www.demoiselle.com.au/store remotely.